# Resending SMS from a received bundle works in emulator, but not in physical device

Tags: android

I am trying to catch an sms, take some decisions and give it to the user. The code below works on the emulator, but it doesn't work on my physical device. Both my phone and the emulator are using android 4.1.2. Any ideas?My service receiver:

```
if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                    //action for sms received
                      bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    //..more code 
                     abortBroadcast();
                     Intent update = new Intent();
                     update.setClassName( "com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");                    update.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                     update.putExtras(bundle);
                     startService(update);}
```

My Manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<receiver android:name="com.example.testap.SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.secretlife.newcall" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.media.STREAM_RING" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `abortBroadcast()`, then you won't have to try to pass the broadcast to the SMS app. The system will just continue to pass it down the priority chain, eventually delivering it to the main SMS app. Also, there is no guarantee that any given device will have the `com.android.mms` package, so your method will definitely fail on any device that does not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I did in the first place. Just do nothing, so the SMS will flow to the SMS app. Still, it crashes my application.

Comment: @user167080 Ah, you didn't mention it was crashing. Please post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: this is what I get:  
02-27 15:43:34.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 15:43:34.928: E/AndroidRuntime(2542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.secretlife.SmsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.secretlife.SmsReceiver

However, the receiver code works if I decide to abort the broadcast and save the SMS somewhere else.

Comment: In the manifest you've posted, you have the Receiver's class name as `com.example.testap.SmsReceiver`. Should it be `com.example.secretlife.SmsReceiver`?

Comment: This is correct, I changed it yesterday. My current manifest.xml: 


       `<receiver android:name="com.example.secretlife.SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="com.example.secretlife.newcall" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.media.STREAM_RING" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: Is it located directly in the `/src/com/example/secretlife/` directory?

Comment: Well, actually my service file is myService.java . So, I added those lines to manifest.xml: 
<receiver android:name="com.example.secretlife.myService" >
            <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="com.example.secretlife.newcall" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.media.STREAM_RING" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: I still get this: 02-27 16:00:42.364: E/AndroidRuntime(2641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.secretlife.myService: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.secretlife.myService cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Comment: You can't list a Service as a `<receiver>`. If you want to start a Service when you receive an SMS, you would do it from the BroadcastReceiver. Get that working first before you try adding other components.